# Lightweight PHP/MySQL CMS for HTML5

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

So far I've build my websites with Typo3 but it's a bit of a heavy beast for smaller sites. I've also done some projects with Drupal and Wordpress but my impression is that they mess up the HTML a lot and it is too much effort to "correct" them.

I like to build some smaller websites with HTML5 now and was wondering which PHP/MySQL-based CMS could be right for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I went with Concrete5 as it was recommended to me by various people and seems to be very well-written! http://www.concrete5.org

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, every publicly available stock CMS system will, ultimately, have the downfall of messy output. This stems from the fact that they attempt to be something for everyone, rather than a targeted product.

Rolling your own CMS is not that big of a challenge with a little PHP knowledge. If you're familiar enough to know what you want and how you would lay it out, there are a ton of great resources for developing your own CMS, including:

- http://www.ssdtutorials.com/premium-tutorials/series/cms-dreamweaver.html
- http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=322&t=Intro_How_to_Build_Custom_PHP_and_MySQL_CMS_Website_Software
- http://www.packtpub.com/cms-design-using-php-and-jquery/book
- http://www.packtpub.com/php-5-cms-framework-development-2nd-edition/book

Essentially, a simple CMS boils down to dynamic page generation with a server-side scripting language and templating, a database to store content, and a backend for management. At it's simplest, you have one page template (your content always is output to a simple template, as in a blog or something where you rarely have different types of output), and your backend consists of a log-in to password protect a form that updates your database.

To get back to the main point, however, HTML5 will only be involved in the output for client-side rendering. That is, if your template is HTML5, your site is HTML5 (for all intents and purposes, at least to your visitors).

Answer (score 1):

A question like this will generally get a lot of opinionated, debate type responses because every developer has different opinions and different tool sets.

For smaller projects, I prefer to use some light weight components and build it rather than using a packaged CMS.

Me personally, for smaller projects:

- **HTML5 Boilerplate**, it gives you a great starting point, and once you
  have used it and are familiar you can quickly customize it to your
  preferences. http://html5boilerplate.com/
- **FlourishLib**, is a great no framework library, it is quick, easy to use and the documentation is great. http://www.flourishlib.com
- **jQuery**, is a great tool for your JS needs.

I spent so much time playing around with other packaged CMS that I found I could have already had the project up and out the door by the time I tweaked the CMS to get what I wanted out of it.

And using this tools you can easily create your own boilerplate to get your project started quickly.

Again, this is just an opinion based on my preferences.

Comment: I don't get the CMS part in this answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out glFusion at http://www.glfusion.org with all the features it has right out of the box.  Unlike allot of other CMS's glFusion is free, including the plugins.  Latest version 1.3.0 as of the time of this posting, will have html5 and also be w3c validated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a [lightweight and fast cms build on HTML5 and CSS3 then Gecko](http://www.cmsgecko.com) should be the right one for you!

Answer (score 0):

Check CouchCMS - i think it is the best one for your purpose www.couchcms.com

Answer (score 0):

Perch CMS (not free but very cheap) is very lightwight, may want to take a look.    http://grabaperch.com/

Answer (score 0):

I really like GetSimple CMS. I use this on a majority of small projects because it is incredibly easy to set up. It is PHP powered, and does not require an SQL Database. Instead it uses XML files to store content.

http://get-simple.info/

As a previous poster mentioned, HTML5 Boilerplate and jQuery provide a quick way to get set up and I often use these in conjunction with each other.